# Excel 2011 dylib search paths on OSX 10.11+

Tags: excel, macos, dyld

What is the logic used to find shared libraries on OSX 10.11+ in Excel 2011?  In OSX 10.10, you could set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, but SIP in OSX 10.11+ does not allow you to overwrite/set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.  So if we wanted to call a shared library from Excel, that seems impossible now.  What locations are searched by Excel 2011 on mac when declaring references to shared libraries?

Answer (score 1):

It should always be possible to use a full path (i.e. `/usr/local/lib/libmng.so`) to specify the library. The `dlopen()` man page specifies that:

> Note: If the main executable is a set[ug]id binary or codesigned with entitlements, then all
>        environment variables are ignored, and only a full path can be used.

I don't believe Excel 2011 is code signed with entitlements, but a full path is the safest way to go.